# TypeError: 'StringVar' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've been working my way through a book on learning to use tkinter and creating GUIs with Python. [Link to Book](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/python-gui-programming-tkinter)

I'm up to chapter 3 and so far so good. I've read the chapter and have gone back to work my way through the code and reconstruct their application. I've copied out all the code word for word as far as I can see but when I run the code I get the following error

`self.input = input_class(self, **input_args)
TypeError: 'StringVar' object is not callable`

I've googled the error and it appears to be something related to a syntax error or simply mismatching variable names at some point. I've looked through what I've written several times and am begining to think I can't see the wood for the trees. I can't see ANY difference in the code I've written to what I've copied from the book or any reason it shouldn't work.

[python GUI TypeError: 'str' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041712/python-gui-typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable)

https://errorcodespro.com/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable/

I've downloaded the sample file that goes with the book and that one runs fine (although it does appear to have been updated somewhat as it is different in parts to the book, but the section highlighted by the error message appears to be the same.)

The code I have written is below (if anyone has the book there are slight differences as I haven't filled out all the form elements as its just repeating placing widgets into the form and I can't see why not including them would cause the error e.g. 
`'self.inputs['Date'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Date", input_var=tk.StringVar())
 self.inputs['Date'].grid(row=0, column=0)':`

I've highlighted the line that is apparently causing the error with >>>>>>>code here<<<<<<<<<< in case anyone thought that was the issue I'm just trying to highlight it for you.

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class LabelInput (tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, label='', input_class=ttk.Entry, input_var=None, input_args=None, label_args=None, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
    input_args = input_args or {}
    label_args = label_args or {}
    self.variable = input_var

    if input_class in (ttk.Checkbutton, ttk.Button, ttk.Radiobutton):
        input_args["text"] = label
        input_args["variable"] = input_var
    else:
        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text=label, **label_args)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
        input_args["textvariable"] = input_var

    >>>>>>>self.input = input_class(self, **input_args)<<<<<<<<<<<<
    self.input.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

def grid(self, sticky=(tk.E + tk.W), **kwargs):
    super().grid(sticky=sticky, **kwargs)

def get(self):
    try:
        if self.variable:
            return self.variable.get()
        elif type(self.input) == tk.Text:
            return self.input.get('1.0', tk.END)
        else:
            return self.input.get()
    except (TypeError, tk.TclError):
        return ''

def set(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
    if type(self.variable) == tk.BooleanVar:
        self.variable.set(bool(value))
    elif self.variable:
        self.variable.set(value, *args, **kwargs)
    elif type(self.input) in (ttk.Checkbutton, ttk.Radiobutton):
        if value:
            self.input.select()
        else:
            self.input.deselect()
    elif type(self.input) == tk.Text:
        self.input.delete('1.0', tk.END)
        self.input.insert('1.0', value)
    else:
        self.input.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.input.insert(0, value)

class DataRecordForm(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

    self.inputs = {}

    recordinfo = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Record Information")

    self.inputs['Date'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Date", input_var=tk.StringVar())
    self.inputs['Date'].grid(row=0, column=0)

    self.inputs['Time'] = LabelInput (recordinfo, "Time", input_class=ttk.Combobox, input_var=tk.StringVar(), input_args={"values": ["8:00", "12:00", "16:00", "20:00"]})
    self.inputs['Time'].grid(row=0, column=1)

    self.inputs['Technician'] = LabelInput (recordinfo, "Technician", input_class=tk.StringVar())
    self.inputs['Technician'].grid(row=0, column=2)

    self.inputs['Lab'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Lab", input_class=ttk.Combobox, input_var=tk.StingVar(), input_args = {"values": ["A", "B", "C"]})
    self.inputs['Labs'].grid(row=1, column=0)

    environmentinfo = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Enivronment Information")

    self.inputs['Humidity'] = LabelInput(environmentinfo, "Humidity (g/m3)", input_class=tk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.DoubleVar(), input_args={"from_": 0.5, "to": 52.0, "increment": .01})
    self.inputs['Humidity'].grid(row=0, column=0)

    self.inputs['Equipment Fault'] = LabelInput(environmentinfo, "Equipment Fault", input_class=ttk.Checkbutton, input_var=tk.BooleanVar())
    self.inputs['Equipment Fault'].grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)

    self.inputs['Notes'] = LabelInput(self, "Notes", input_class=tk.Text, input_args={"width": 75, "height": 10})
    self.inputs['Notes'].grid(sticky="w", row=3, column=0)

def get(self):
    data = {}
    for key, widget in self.inputs.items():
        data[key] = widget.get()
    return data

def reset(self):
    for widget in self.inputs.values():
        widget.set('')

class Application(tk.Tk):
""" ROOT WINDOW """
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.title("Data Entry")
    self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    ttk.Label(self, text="Data Entry", font=("TkDefaultFont", 16)).grid(row=0)

    self.recordform = DataRecordForm(self)
    self.recordform.grid(row=1, padx=10)

    self.savebutton = ttk.Button(self, text="Save", command=self.on_save)
    self.savebutton.grid(sticky=tk.E, row=2, padx=10)

    self.status = tk.StringVar()
    self.statusbar = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.status)
    self.statusbar.grid(sticky=tk.W + tk.E, row=3, padx=10)

    def on_save(self):
        datestring = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        filename = "Data Entry_{}.csv".format(datestring)
        newfile = not os.path.exists(filename)

        data = self.recordform.get()

        with open(filename, 'a') as fh:
            csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(fh, fieldnames=data.keys())
            if newfile:
                csvwriter.writeheader()
            csvwriter.writerow(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

The following is the sample code I have downloaded which accompanies the book. As stated above it does appear to have been updated but the section which is problematic for me appears to be the same.

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk`


class LabelInput(tk.Frame):
"""A widget containing a label and input together."""

def __init__(self, parent, label='', input_class=ttk.Entry,
             input_var=None, input_args=None, label_args=None,
             **kwargs):
    super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
    input_args = input_args or {}
    label_args = label_args or {}
    self.variable = input_var

    if input_class in (ttk.Checkbutton, ttk.Button, ttk.Radiobutton):
        input_args["text"] = label
        input_args["variable"] = input_var
    else:
        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text=label, **label_args)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
        input_args["textvariable"] = input_var

    self.input = input_class(self, **input_args)
    self.input.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

def grid(self, sticky=(tk.E + tk.W), **kwargs):
    super().grid(sticky=sticky, **kwargs)

def get(self):
    if self.variable:
        return self.variable.get()
    elif type(self.input) == tk.Text:
        return self.input.get('1.0', tk.END)
    else:
        return self.input.get()

def set(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
    if type(self.variable) == tk.BooleanVar:
            self.variable.set(bool(value))
    elif self.variable:
            self.variable.set(value, *args, **kwargs)
    elif type(self.input).__name__.endswith('button'):
        if value:
            self.input.select()
        else:
            self.input.deselect()
    elif type(self.input) == tk.Text:
        self.input.delete('1.0', tk.END)
        self.input.insert('1.0', value)
    else:
        self.input.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.input.insert(0, value)


class DataRecordForm(tk.Frame):
"""The input form for our widgets"""

def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
    # A dict to keep track of input widgets
    self.inputs = {}

    # Build the form
    # recordinfo section
    recordinfo = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Record Information")

    # line 1
    self.inputs['Date'] = LabelInput(
        recordinfo, "Date",
        input_var=tk.StringVar()
    )
    self.inputs['Date'].grid(row=0, column=0)
    self.inputs['Time'] = LabelInput(
        recordinfo, "Time",
        input_class=ttk.Combobox,
        input_var=tk.StringVar(),
        input_args={"values": ["8:00", "12:00", "16:00", "20:00"]}
    )
    self.inputs['Time'].grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.inputs['Technician'] = LabelInput(
        recordinfo, "Technician",
        input_var=tk.StringVar()
    )
    self.inputs['Technician'].grid(row=0, column=2)

    # line 2
    self.inputs['Lab'] = LabelInput(
        recordinfo, "Lab",
        input_class=ttk.Combobox,
        input_var=tk.StringVar(),
        input_args={"values": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]}
    )
    self.inputs['Lab'].grid(row=1, column=0)
    self.inputs['Plot'] = LabelInput(
        recordinfo, "Plot",
        input_class=ttk.Combobox,
        input_var=tk.IntVar(),
        input_args={"values": list(range(1, 21))}
    )
    self.inputs['Plot'].grid(row=1, column=1)
    self.inputs['Seed sample'] = LabelInput(
        recordinfo, "Seed sample",
        input_var=tk.StringVar()
    )
    self.inputs['Seed sample'].grid(row=1, column=2)

    recordinfo.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

    # Environment Data
    environmentinfo = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Environment Data")
    self.inputs['Humidity'] = LabelInput(
        environmentinfo, "Humidity (g/m³)",
        input_class=tk.Spinbox,
        input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
        input_args={"from_": 0.5, "to": 52.0, "increment": .01}
    )
    self.inputs['Humidity'].grid(row=0, column=0)
    self.inputs['Light'] = LabelInput(
        environmentinfo, "Light (klx)",
        input_class=tk.Spinbox,
        input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
        input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 100, "increment": .01}
    )
    self.inputs['Light'].grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.inputs['Temperature'] = LabelInput(
        environmentinfo, "Tenmperature (°C)",
        input_class=tk.Spinbox,
        input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
        input_args={"from_": 4, "to": 40, "increment": .01}
    )
    self.inputs['Temperature'].grid(row=0, column=2)
    self.inputs['Equipment Fault'] = LabelInput(
        environmentinfo, "Equipment Fault",
        input_class=ttk.Checkbutton,
        input_var=tk.BooleanVar()
    )
    self.inputs['Equipment Fault'].grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)
    environmentinfo.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

    # Plant Data section
    plantinfo = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Plant Data")

    self.inputs['Plants'] = LabelInput(
        plantinfo, "Plants",
        input_class=tk.Spinbox,
        input_var=tk.IntVar(),
        input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 20}
    )
    self.inputs['Plants'].grid(row=0, column=0)
    self.inputs['Blossoms'] = LabelInput(
        plantinfo, "Blossoms",
        input_class=tk.Spinbox,
        input_var=tk.IntVar(),
        input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000}
    )
    self.inputs['Blossoms'].grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.inputs['Fruit'] = LabelInput(
        plantinfo, "Fruit",
        input_class=tk.Spinbox,
        input_var=tk.IntVar(),
        input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000}
    )
    self.inputs['Fruit'].grid(row=0, column=2)

    # Height data
    self.inputs['Min Height'] = LabelInput(
        plantinfo, "Min Height (cm)",
        input_class=tk.Spinbox,
        input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
        input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000, "increment": .01}
    )
    self.inputs['Min Height'].grid(row=1, column=0)
    self.inputs['Max Height'] = LabelInput(
        plantinfo, "Max Height (cm)",
        input_class=tk.Spinbox,
        input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
        input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000, "increment": .01}
    )
    self.inputs['Max Height'].grid(row=1, column=1)
    self.inputs['Median Height'] = LabelInput(
        plantinfo, "Median Height (cm)",
        input_class=tk.Spinbox,
        input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
        input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000, "increment": .01}
    )
    self.inputs['Median Height'].grid(row=1, column=2)

    plantinfo.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

    # Notes section
    self.inputs['Notes'] = LabelInput(
        self, "Notes",
        input_class=tk.Text,
        input_args={"width": 75, "height": 10}
    )
    self.inputs['Notes'].grid(sticky=tk.W, row=3, column=0)

    # default the form
    self.reset()

def get(self):
    """Retrieve data from form as a dict"""

    # We need to retrieve the data from Tkinter variables
    # and place it in regular Python objects

    data = {}
    for key, widget in self.inputs.items():
        data[key] = widget.get()
    return data

def reset(self):
    """Resets the form entries"""

    # clear all values
    for widget in self.inputs.values():
        widget.set('')


class Application(tk.Tk):
"""Application root window"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.title("ABQ Data Entry Application")
    self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    ttk.Label(
        self,
        text="ABQ Data Entry Application",
        font=("TkDefaultFont", 16)
    ).grid(row=0)

    self.recordform = DataRecordForm(self)
    self.recordform.grid(row=1, padx=10)

    self.savebutton = ttk.Button(self, text="Save", command=self.on_save)
    self.savebutton.grid(sticky=tk.E, row=2, padx=10)

    # status bar
    self.status = tk.StringVar()
    self.statusbar = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.status)
    self.statusbar.grid(sticky=(tk.W + tk.E), row=3, padx=10)

    self.records_saved = 0

def on_save(self):
    """Handles save button clicks"""

    # For now, we save to a hardcoded filename with a datestring.
    # If it doesnt' exist, create it,
    # otherwise just append to the existing file
    datestring = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    filename = "abq_data_record_{}.csv".format(datestring)
    newfile = not os.path.exists(filename)

    data = self.recordform.get()

    with open(filename, 'a') as fh:
        csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(fh, fieldnames=data.keys())
        if newfile:
            csvwriter.writeheader()
        csvwriter.writerow(data)

    self.records_saved += 1
    self.status.set(
        "{} records saved this session".format(self.records_saved))
    self.recordform.reset()


if __name__ == "__main__":

app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

This code works but I just can't work out what the difference is that is making this version work and mine fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `DataRecordForm` class `__init__()` function you are creating a number of `LabelInput` instances. Amongst others:

```
self.inputs['Technician'] = LabelInput (recordinfo, "Technician", input_class=tk.StringVar())
```

This call passes the `input_class` argument as `tk.StringVar()`.

From what I understand you should pass it as `input_var` and not `input_class`. This also seems to be the only line with this error.

Comment: That's it thank you!! I couldn't see the wood for the trees